# Is there any way to store images so user can't see them or delete them?

Tags: android, image, android-studio

I am looking for a way to store images in android device either user cant see or open them or unable to delete them. Main idea behind it is I have to use the image as chat background in chat application. Whatsapp has similar functionality first background image is saved in other folder, if you delete that image then also image comes. I don't know how Whatsapp handles. Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Its just being redownloaded.

Comment: if your saving image into sdcard use dot before folder name and folder will be hidden

Comment: @FrozenFire there will be many images, there may be chances of OOM or some lag later on

Comment: @Enzokie you mean for every chat background whatsapp save image at server

Comment: @PrashantSharma Good idea, What if user dont have sdcard?

Comment: @Jagjit Singh if you store images directly to phone /SD memory it still have chance to OOM.

Comment: @Jagjit Singh PrashantSharma's method can be used also for phone memory, not just SD card.

Comment: All unique images that are not native to the app are stored in the server. While the resource images are not.

Comment: @FrozenFire I am loading images from Uri, chances are less as compared

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions.

- You can save images and data in sharedpreferences
- in sqlite database.
- You can also encrypt data and store it anywhere and decrypt while loading image back to app.

Keep in mind that user can access data saved by first two methods with root permission.

**Edit:** if you want to keep it simple, just create a folder named Systemfiles and save image with name "file" without jpg/bmp/png etc. No body gonna notice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

1. Save images into database, but I wowldn't recommend it.
2. Save images into a folder, and manually add an empty file names **.nomedia** in same location.
3. Use your own image format, or zip images, or rename them, makes them looks doesn't like image file. For example, change *pic01.jpg* to *data01.abc*.

These will prevent your images from showing on any other photo/gallary APP.

Answer (score 0):

Save the image in Base64 format so the user will not be able to see it. Use the following code to encrypt it.

```
file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/SDCard/myimage.jpg";
Bitmap selectedImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
String strBase64=Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, 0);
```

Use the following code decrypt it to bitmap and set it into imageview.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```